# show latex document in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, latex

is there any way to render in React a Latex document? 
I tried *react-latex* ([react-latex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-latex)), but it renders only latex strings. I want to render a whole document like this: [overleaf-project](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5c8bd291cef2c453ba2e842b).